# Pytest fixture scope and @pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

I am a little confused about fixture scope in pytest. Say I have a fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def data():
    data = generate_some_data()
    yeild data
    teardown()
```

and a test function

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("runs", ["one", "two"])
def my_test(data, runs):
    run_some_tests(runs)
```

My understanding is that in this case, the generate_some_data() function will be run for each parameterisation, with the fixture beign setup then torn down. Is it possible to keep the scope so that the fixture is only setup and torn down once, for all paramterizations?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the fixture executed once for a function and cannot have it scoped for a `session` or `module`, then you might be able to use a `class` scope (with moving your test into a class)

```py
import pytest

_iter = iter(range(10))


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def iter_next():
    yield next(_iter)


class TestUseFixtureUsedOnce:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("run", list("abcdefghij"))
    def test_function(self, iter_next, run):
        print(iter_next, run)
```

Running this prints (not counting pytest output):

```
0 a
0 b
0 c
0 d
0 e
0 f
0 g
0 h
0 i
0 j
```